# Define DB Constraint

Tags: constraints, rdbms

Is it possible to define a constraint like this:

```
A <- SELECT Enrolment course = x AND student = y
B <- PROJECT A OVER student
COUNT(B) < 3
```

I'm particularly interested in the "AND" part. I know from my books that the rest is OK.

The syntax is based on Codd [1] and does not apply to any particular DBMS.

**Sources:**

1. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a *constraint,* no, not in general. That's a little complex for a constraint.

If you want something like that, you usually have to resort to triggers, which can usually run arbitrarily complex code. A before-insert and before-update trigger, assuming your DBMS has them, should do the trick.

Please note that triggers almost certainly have a performance impact and they should only be used where necessary but they *should* be used if the data has to follow rules, don't let anyone tell you differently).

The general rule is: if the constraint is a property of your *data,* it should be done by the DBMS itself (with constraints or triggers or whatever vendor-specific things you may have available to you).

However, if the constraint is a property of the *application,* it should be handled by the application without any effort by the DBMS.

In reality, I don't think I've *ever* seen that latter situation arise since the application and data tend to be bound pretty tightly, but I've never seen little green men either and they may well exist :-)

Comment: I should add its an Enterprise Constraint. For the rest its true what you say, a RDBMS is abstract from the application processes only on paper, in practice they are an interwoven spool.

Comment: Agree, but how would you define -with above syntax- that a student may only enroll up to 2 times in the same course?

Comment: With the above syntax, no idea. With a concrete syntax, such as with DB2, you simply create a before-insert trigger which opens a cursor to count the rows where the student has enrolled in the course. Then, if that count is already 2 (or greater), just whrow an exception: `SIGNAL SQLSTATE '80000' ('Enrolled too many times');`. There's an example at http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/yip/0111yip.html